# How does Chrome distrust Symantec Certificates?

Tags: tls, certificate-authority, openssl, chromium

Sometime back Google Chrome had announced [plans](https://security.googleblog.com/2017/09/chromes-plan-to-distrust-symantec.html) to distrust Symantec certificates. I am trying to figure out how this is done for a POC.

When I visit chase.com on Google Chrome, I get the following message in the dev console:

> The SSL certificate used to load resources from https://www.chase.com
>   will be distrusted in M70. Once distrusted, users will be prevented
>   from loading these resources. See https://g.co/chrome/symantecpkicerts
>   for more information.

From the Chromium source, I could see that they have a list of hashes that they check against - [symantec_certs.cc](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/net/cert/symantec_certs.cc?dr=C) and in this [README.md](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/net/data/ssl/symantec/README.md) they use the following openssl command to get the hashes from the certificates.

```
for f in roots/*.pem; 
do openssl x509 -noout -pubkey -in "${f}" | openssl asn1parse -inform pem -out /tmp/pubkey.out -noout; 
digest=`cat /tmp/pubkey.out | openssl dgst -sha256 -c | awk -F " " '{print $2}' | sed s/:/,0x/g `; 
echo "0x${digest} ${f##*/}"; 
done | sort
```

Now for `chase.com`, I got the certs using the following command

```
openssl s_client -host chase.com -port 443 -prexit -showcerts
```

This outputs two certs both of which I copied to separate files (from 'begin certificate' to 'end certificate') `cert1.cert` and `cert2.cert`

To get the hashes, executed the following

```
for f in ./*.cert; 
do cat "${f}" | openssl x509 -noout -pubkey | openssl asn1parse -inform pem -out /tmp/pubkey.out -noout; 
digest=`cat /tmp/pubkey.out | openssl dgst -sha256 -c | awk -F " " '{print $2}' | sed s/:/,0x/g `; 
echo "0x${digest}"; 
done
```

which gives

```
0x14,0x72,0x0b,0x47,0x2b,0x12,0x3d,0xc2,0xfd,0xcc,0x13,0x2a,0x81,0x09,0xc7,0x29,0x97,0x13,0x36,0xaf,0x95,0x38,0x9f,0x89,0x12,0xa4,0x71,0xa8,0x78,0xdd,0xb7,0x37
0x80,0xcc,0x56,0x3a,0xb5,0xf8,0x3c,0xc4,0x1e,0xb0,0xaf,0x6a,0x14,0xd6,0xd8,0x07,0x18,0xc1,0x7e,0x35,0x2f,0x96,0x49,0xff,0xbc,0xdd,0x67,0xf8,0xbf,0x65,0x13,0x91
```

both of which aren't in `symantec_certs.cc`

I believe the certificate chain doesn't contain the Root CA certificate, am I supposed calculate the Root's public key hash also and check it against the know distrusted roots? If yes, how to get the Root certificate?

Comment: You might want to look at this question to get the root: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/368123/how-to-extract-the-root-ca-and-subordinate-ca-from-a-certificate-chain-in-linux

Comment: @krishnaraj: Did you manage to solve this question?

Comment: @StackzOfZtuff Yes, I did have to check with the root CA's hash and I wrote the solution in Java.

Comment: See https://github.com/DanielRuf/symantecpkicerts/blob/master/ca-list.json which I have extracte from all child CAs from https://crt.sh/ base on the affected roots. Chrome checks them all.